# node.js filesystem mangles Cygwin drive name

Tags: node.js, cygwin

I recently installed Cygwin64 after using Cygwin32 for quite some time and I'm now having problems with one of our production scripts. Node.js's 'readFileSync' seems to be prepending the windows drive letter to the path and then failing to resolve - e.g. /cygdrive/c/foo becomes c:/cygdrive/c/foo.

I've found various mentions of similar issues online but so far I've been unable to resolve this problem. My co-worker has a seemingly identical setup and does not experience the problem.

Here it is in a nutshell -

```
$ cat filetest.js
var fs = require('fs');
function main(argv) {
    console.log("fileName => ", argv[2]);
    var data = fs.readFileSync(argv[2], 'utf8');
    console.log("success");
}
main(process.argv);

$ s/node filetest.js filetest.js
fileName =>  filetest.js
success

$ ls -l /cygdrive/c/temp/Test.txt
----rwx---+ 1 bdodd Domain Users 14 Jun  3 14:12 /cygdrive/c/temp/Test.txt

$ s/node filetest.js /cygdrive/c/temp/Test.txt
fileName =>  /cygdrive/c/temp/Test.txt

  fs.js:338
    return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                   ^
  Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\cygdrive\c\temp\Test.txt'
```

and just for completeness...

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab
#
#    This file is read once by the first process in a Cygwin process tree.
#    To pick up changes, restart all Cygwin processes.  For a description
#    see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

# This is default anyway:
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0

$ cd /cygdrive/
$ ls -l
total 40
d---rwx---+ 1 NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller 0 Jun  3 14:09 c
dr-xrwxr-x  1 Unknown+User                Unix_Group+33               0 Apr 29  2014 u
```

Insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I guess node is expecting a windows path as it is not cygwin aware. What's happen with `s/node filetest.js $(cygpath -w -a /cygdrive/c/temp/Test.txt)`

Comment: Yes - node is expecting a windows path. Do you know how this gets configured?

`$ s/node filetest.js $(cygpath -w -a /cygdrive/c/temp/Test.txt)
fileName =>  C:\temp\Test.txt
success
`